# Why do we even need to create a new instance obj in `new` method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
  def new
    @post = Post.new
    ...
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])
    ...
  end
```

Since in `create` method, we will initiate a new obj by the parameters we gave anyway, why do we even need `@post = Post.new` in the `new` method? It doesn't make sense, does it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your `new` view needs a `Post` object to render a form from. Instantiating a new one gives you that object for your view to render a form around.

Comment: Then what's the point for the form to need an obj to be rendered? What is that required object used for? There has to be something reasonable.

Comment: Rails infers a bunch of things from the form subject when you use `form_for`, including the path for the form to POST or PUT to, the types of the fields, etc. You don't have to use a blank Post instance if you're not using form_for, but it's certainly cleaner to since it lets you re-use the form in the case of failed validations with no extra work.

Comment: It also lets you share the form (usually as a partial template) between `new` and `edit`. When a newly instantiated AR object (not saved to the DB) is passed to `form_for`, Rails will generate a form which posts to `create`. When an existing record is passed to `form_for`, it will generate a form which posts to `update`.